# Python 3 - how to retrieve return value from inside a dictionary comprehension for use in another method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

Python newbie learning dictionary comprehensions here. Consider the following example dictionary that has further dictionary as its value (are they called "multidimensional dictionaries"? Just wondering.):

```
 maindictionary = {
'key1':{'key11':'value11','key12':'value12'},
'key2':{'key21':'value21','key22':'value22'}, 
'key3':{'key31':'value31','key32':'value32'},
'key4':{'key41':'value41','key42':'value42'}
}
```

I'd like to traverse through the main dictionary in a function within a dictionary comprehension that yields a result, which could then be utilized within that loop in another function. The algorithm is like follows:

- Loop through the dictionary, and send value for each key to
  `functionA`, unless key is equal to key3 or key4.
- Take result from `functionA` and pass it to `functionB`
- Go to next iteration.

`functionA` returns a dictionary as well. `functionB` just prints out the result.

I have a vague idea that it would look something similar to the code below, and this is what I have tested so far and it gives syntax errors:

```
{result:functionA(v) for (k,v) in maindictionary if (k != 'key3' or k != 'key4')}
   functionB(result)
```

I could be totally wrong on the syntax here, so if you could point me to a good dictionary comprehension resource (not the official python docs, they are hard to understand for a starter), that would be great!

**EDIT**:

The output from `functionA` would be the creation of two dictionaries, `{'key11':'value11'}` and `{'key21':'value21'}` (per each iteration). These would then be fed into `functionB`, which would output `value11` and then `value21` (per iteration).

I want to use the result from `functionA`, i.e. a dictionary that is fed into `functionB`, which then retrieves its value.

Comment: You say you want a dict comprehension, but what are the keys and values for the dict? If I understand the question correctly, the values should be `functionB(functionA(v))`, but what are the keys?

Comment: a `dict-comprehension` is used because it creates `dict`s. Ofc you can run functions in a dict comprehension but **do you want to store** their results in a `dict`? If not just loop. And what is `result`?

Comment: what is your desired output? can you give a concrete example?

Comment: @Rawing, the keys are also dictionaries. or am I missing something here? Confused now..

Comment: You can't use dictionaries as dict keys. It would probably be easier to understand the question if you include the implementations of `functionA` and `functionB` and the result/output you want.

Comment: The output of `functionB` would be a print out of the values of key11 and key21

Comment: Don't use comprehensions for doing things other than creating the data structures. It sounds like you want a loop.

Comment: @Rawing, sorry I meant the values are also dictionaries, not keys! :D

Comment: @omrakhur I am affraid you are trying to be *Pythonic* the wrong way and end up being *confused* and *writing bad code*. Just loop.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis, way to encourage newcomers to Python!

Comment: @omrakhur Not sure how I come off as text but I meant it in a constructive newcomer-welcoming way. Just trying to help. Comprehensions are indeed cool and they are often abused because of it.

Comment: i know I am wrong here, that's what I mentioned in the question above. So if you could please tell me how the desired output could be achieved in a loop, I'd appreciate an answer that could help me learn

Comment: If the answer from @Linch raises an error, make sure `result` is something hashable and run it again. It should work.

Comment: The problem is we aren't sure what your desired output is @omrakhur, if you could expand on your original question to give a more detailed example of what you would expect as the output that would allow us to help you better.

Comment: @JakeConkerton-Darby, please find edits above.

Answer (score 3):

A dictionary comprehension is meant to create dictionaries. In your particular case, you're working with a dictionary that already exists. I do not believe you are looking at the right paradigm. I would suggest using something like a generator, and passing each value individually, like this:

```
def functionA(__dict):
    for k in __dict:
        if k not in ['key3', 'key4']:
            yield __dict[k]

main_dict = {...}
for item in functionA(main_dict):
    functionB(item)
```

`functionA` ia a generator, which loops through the dictionary, yielding items for valid keys which is in turn passed to `functionB`.

Answer (score 0):

```
functionB({'result'+str(i):functionA(d[1]) for i,d in enumerate(maindictionary.items()) if d[0] not in ("key3","key4")})
list(map(lambda d: functionB(d[1]), resA.items()))
```

Your final results will be a list if you return any value from functionB else execute the function and return a list of None

Answer (score 0):

As it was mentioned in the previous comments, dictcomprehension is meant to create dictionnaries, if you do not intend to create a dictionnary then why bother.

That being said, if you *absolutely want* list/dict comprehension you can write code that use/abuse them as they behave as limited `for`-loops.
So here are two versions for you, first one using regular for loops second one abusing dict-comprehension as for-loops:

```
maindictionary = {
'key1':{'key11':'value11','key12':'value12'},
'key2':{'key21':'value21','key22':'value22'}, 
'key3':{'key31':'value31','key32':'value32'},
'key4':{'key41':'value41','key42':'value42'}
}

def functionA(d):
    #splits a dictionary into several dictionaries
    for k,v in d.items():
        yield {k:v}

def functionB(d):
    #print one value from d
    print(list(d.values())[0])



#method 1
print("method 1:")
for k,v in maindictionary.items():
    if k != 'key3' and k != 'key4' :
        for small_dict in functionA(v):
            functionB(small_dict)

#method 2
print("method 2:")
{'dummy key':{'dummy key':functionB(small_dict) for small_dict in functionA(v)} for (k,v) in maindictionary.items() if (k != 'key3' and k != 'key4')}
```

Output :

```
method 1:
value11
value12
value21
value22
method 2:
value11
value12
value21
value22
```

Answer (score -1):

remove extra `if` in condition:

```
{result:functionA(v) for (k,v) in maindictionary if (k != 'key3' or k != 'key4')}
```

Comment: even if `result` is defined as something hashable anyway, you will keep overwriting it's value.